# Android BroadcastReceiver NOT working with IntentFilter

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, screen, intentfilter, proximitysensor

```
The control is not Entering inside the --> receiver = (BroadcastReceiver) (context, intent) -> { ===== loop
```

I am trying to lock the screen(android) and its not entering the loop after creating BroadcastReceiver object. I am trying to lock the screen using the proximity sensor.

```
public class ScreenLockerService extends Service {

    protected static final String TAG = ScreenLockerService.class.getCanonicalName();
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        ProximitySensor.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

        System.out.println("Screen is being locked");
//        ScreenLock.lockScreen(getApplicationContext());
  //      Vibration.vibrate(getApplicationContext());
receiver = (BroadcastReceiver) (context, intent) -> {
                System.out.println("Screen....");

                try {
                    ProximitySensor proximitySensor = ProximitySensor.getInstance(context);
                    if (proximitySensor.hasProximitySensorHardware() && proximitySensor.isClose()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "lock");
                        if (CallStatus.isCallStateIdle(context)) {
                            ScreenLock.lockScreen(context);
                            Vibration.vibrate(context);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exception occurred: " + e);
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
```

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` is an `abstract` class, not an `interface`. AFAIK, Java's lambdas still don't work with `abstract` classes.

Comment: Can u please elaborate on this..?

Comment: Just create a `BroadcastReceiver` subclass as you would normally.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank u very much..I did this..Still not working..what must be the problem?..Thanks..............receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                System.out.println("Screen....");

Answer (score 0):

have you registered your broadcastreceiver???if not then register it please
and if u just want to lock your device the you can do it using device policy managaer or key

Comment: Thank you very much..Do I need to register the receiver before intentFilter..?

Comment: yes and also if u want u can simple register your receiver in manifest by declaring it

Comment: please up my ans if u find it suitable